# Validating a partial model within a view with a strongly typed view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a View called LogIn which has a strongly typed view (ViewModelBase). The login View has a partial called LoginForm which also has a strongly typed view (LogInFormModel).

How do I display validation errors for the LoginFormModel? As when I click the login button I have to somehow pass the ModelState to the LoginForm partial going via the LogIn view which is expecting ViewModelBase.

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462267/asp-net-mvc2-multiple-partial-view-and-validation) but there only seems to be one answer and that is to use AJAX which I am reluctant to use at this stage as I belive there must be an alternative way using HttpPost.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your Model looks like. But if you have a "`LogInFormModel`" as property in the "`ViewModelBase`" then if you put `ValidationSummary excludePropertyErrors` to `false` this should works for you:

```
     <%: Html.ValidationSummary(false)%>
// do some stuff here to deal with ViewModelBase
     <%:Html.EditorFor(model => model.LogInFormModel)%>
```